# How to capture with angular the event when a new window tab is created

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to capture with angular the event when a new window tab is created. I already know that we can capture the event onload the window using:

```
    var windowElement = angular.element($window);
    windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {
        //Code here           
    });
```

Is there any like this?

```
    var windowElement = angular.element($window);
    windowElement.on('beforeunloadtab', function (event) {
        //Code here           
    });
```

Comment: Open new tab ? you mean blank tab ?

Comment: `beforeunload` is called when closing the current tab/window, I don't think there is an event for when you create a new window/tab

Comment: Yes, I want to capture the event when I right click on the link and then click on "Open link in new tab"